# How to add a tag to an XML file in Python at a specific location?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML file with multiple comments that looks like:

```
<tags>
  <!--comments-->
  <tag>
     <tag1>a</tag1>
     <tag2>b</tag2>
  </tag>
  <tag>
     <tag1>d</tag1>
     <tag2>e</tag2>
  </tag>
</tags>
```

Programatically in Python, through `xml.etree`, I want to modify this file to look like this while preserving the comments:

```
<tags>
  <!--comments-->
  <tag>
     <tag1>a</tag1>
     <tag2>b</tag2>
     <tag3>c</tag3>
  </tag>
  <tag>
     <tag1>d</tag1>
     <tag2>e</tag2>
     <tag3>f</tag3>
  </tag>
</tags>
```

How can I accomplish that? `tree.write(open(file, "w"))` ends up overwriting the comments and `tree.write(open(file, "a"))` writes to the end of the file, which is not what I want either.

Comment: This might help you find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772739/python-xml-etree-elementtree-append-to-subelement

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573807/faithfully-preserve-comments-in-parsed-xml-python-2-7

Comment: *"ends up overwriting the comments"*: Using `lxml` does preserve `<!-- comment -->` by default.